# How to change a single character font after writing long document?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

Using `classicthesis`. How to change a single math caracter, say `J`? I know how to do it by just by adding an extra symbol:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{CMletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}   
\DeclareMathSymbol{\J}{\mathord}{CMletters}{"4B}
```

I'd like to obtain `J` permanently leaving the rest of the alphabet untouched, though. Of course

```
  $\J$
```

produces the desired result and it wouldn't matter to *begin* a document writing an extra slash for each math-J. But I already wrote it and I'd like to change the font to `\mathlord`-J. In my document I would like to add some type of preamble that allows me to change all the

```
 $J$
```

in math mode, so that they appear with the mentioned font. Is that possible?

Comment: To be honest, i am not sure what the current situation is and what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a [minimal test case](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) that shows the current state?

Comment: It should be ``\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{CMletters}{`J}``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way would be

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{CMletters}{`J}
```

but I'm not really sure you want it.

The main ingredient is that `classicthesis` loads `mathpazo`, so we can show a minimal example as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\mathchardef\oldJ=\mathcode`J % just to show the difference

\DeclareSymbolFont{CMletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{J}{\mathalpha}{CMletters}{`J}

\begin{document}
$A+J=I$ is with the J from CM

$A+\oldJ=C$ is with the J from mathpazo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Needless to say, the “old” version is much better.